# Why is my domdocument code not working?

Tags: php, laravel, dom

I'm trying to do some error handling but it doesn't work.

```
foreach ($meta as $node) {
        if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description' && $node->getAttribute('content') > 0) {
            $ts->description = $node->getAttribute('content');
        }
        else {
            $ts->description = 'No description found';
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work.. It cannot find the right meta tag. Instead of finding the meta tag for description it finds `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Declaration $ts:

```
$ts = new Scan;

$ts->save();
```

It's for saving it to the database in Laravel.

Comment: Please specify why this is not working. Give an error message for example. Please refer to the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Can you also provide the declaration and the use of `$ts`?

Comment: Hi, i've editted my post once again :)

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: I've rolled back the addition of an answer to the question, please post it as an answer instead (see the "Your Answer" section below).